# Trying to delete a row if no data in row A:J

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete a row if there is no data from `A:J`

I have found this code and been trying to edit it, but this is deleting the whole sheet's data eventually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
 Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim rngBlanks As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngBlanks = Columns(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rngBlanks Is Nothing Then
            rngBlanks.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Which row are you trying to delete?

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to delete a row if no data in row A:J

What code is doing is individually checking the columns and not the range `A:J` as your title suggests. It is very much possible that your entire data is getting deleted because of this. Lets say `A1` has some data but `B1` doesn't. So your code will delete `Row 1`. What you have to do is to check if say `A1:J1` is blank.

I think this is what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngBlanks As Range
    Dim i As Long, lRow As Long, Ret As Long

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        '~~> Get the last row in that sheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

        '~~> Loop through the rows to find which range is blank
        For i = 1 To lRow
            Ret = Application.Evaluate("=COUNTA(A" & i & ":J" & i & ")")
            If Ret = 0 Then
                If rngBlanks Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngBlanks = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set rngBlanks = Union(rngBlanks, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    '~~~> Delete the range
    If Not rngBlanks Is Nothing Then rngBlanks.Delete
End Sub
```

Another way would be to use Autofilter to delete those ranges

Answer (score -1):

I stepped through your code with a sheet having some non-blank cells in columns A:J down to row 15. Rows 16:18 were entirely blank and D19=1. You want to delete rows that have blanks in every cell from A:J.

On the first iteration of your For..Next loop rngBlanks was not Nothing because typing

```
?rngBlanks.address
```

returned $A$1,$A$5:$A$19. A2:A4 were not blank.  When you execute

```
Set rngBlanks = Columns(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
```

it looks for any blanks in column A which is not what you wanted to test. You want to test each row, probably within your ActiveSheet.UsedRange to see if columns A:J are all blank.  So you need to define a variable

```
Dim Rw as Range
```

and iterate through each Rw in UsedRange

```
For Each Rw in ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

`If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(range(cells(Rw,1),cells(Rw,10))) =0 Then`

```
    Rw.EntireRow.Delete
```

I could post the entire code here but what I've given should put you on the right track.

Comment: Code that deletes rows one at a time needs to iterate backwards or it will skip rows.

Comment: Also, it should be `rw.row` or you'll get a runtime error. Also, the count of blanks should be 10. There's other problems, but you get the idea :). -1