# Excel Macro to make new rows with predefined formatting and formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with more than 2000 rows.

I use the below macro to add a blank rows with a change in value of cloumn A1.

```
Sub AddBlankRows()
'
Dim iRow As Integer
Range("a1").Select
'
iRow = 1
'
Do
'![enter image description here][1]
If Cells(iRow + 1, 1) <> Cells(iRow, 1) Then
    Cells(iRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    iRow = iRow + 2
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, 1).Text = ""
'
End Sub
```

[image]

Is there a way insert the row *(same with the above macro)* with a fourmula and a predefined formatting?

Comment: Yes. What formula and formatting do you want to put? Also Shifting the Row down in loop can make your code very slow. See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195515/trying-to-delete-a-row-if-no-data-in-row-aj/19196119#19196119) method of using `UNION`. You could then insert the row in the end.

Comment: Another TIP: Please do not use `Integer` for Rows. from xl2007+ the number of rows have gone up to `1048576` and hence a `Long` is advised.

Comment: I have added an sample excel file,in the highlighted row there is a count for the no of days (the formatting of which should be as numbers) and the rest of the fields are totals of the above.http://i.stack.imgur.com/2NdTV.jpg

Comment: Why not use inbuilt `SUBTOTALS` instead of macros then?

Comment: I have more than 2000 rows of data with blank rows after each 30 or 31 lines.The blank rows have the calculation as shown in the sample excel sheet.

Comment: Did you read my last comment? You don't need VBA for this. You can achieve what you want using `SUBTOTALS` See [THIS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/calculating-subtotals-and-working-with-levels-in-excel-HA001109798.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the sample code.

```
 Sub AddBlankRows()


    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim cursor As Long
    cursor = 2

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If (LCase(Trim(.Cells(i, 1))) <> LCase(Trim(.Cells(i + 1, 1)))) Then
                .Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
                .Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                lastRow = lastRow + 1

                .Cells(i + 1, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Count(.Range(.Cells(cursor, 2), .Cells(i, 2)))
                .Cells(i + 1, 2).NumberFormat = "0"

                .Cells(i + 1, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(cursor, 3), .Cells(i, 3)))
                .Cells(i + 1, 3).NumberFormat = "0.00"


                i = i + 2
                cursor = i
            End If
        Next


        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow

        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Count(.Range(.Cells(cursor, 2), .Cells(lastRow, 2)))
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).NumberFormat = "0"

        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(cursor, 3), .Cells(lastRow, 3)))
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).NumberFormat = "0.00"


    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: can a line color be added to the newly added rows?